# Почему при подключении через WireGuard на устройствах Apple не открывается chat.openai.com?

Tags: vpn, apple, wireguard, chatgpt

**Ситуация такая**: Есть VPS сервер в Европе, который использует интернет их местного провайдера. VPS куплен еще весной 2023 года. На нем развернут WireGuard. Использую этот сервер как личный VPN. Естественно для каждого члена семьи, а именно для каждого устройства свой ключ для подключения. Все работало отлично, все сайты открывались, везде куда я хотел получить доступ - получал.

**Но в сентябре появилась проблема**: На всех моих устройствах Apple (Такие как Mac OS и iOS) перестал открываться ChatGPT (chat.openai.com). Другие сайты как открывались, так и открывается. (Важно!!! На Windows все осталось по прежнему - ChatGPT работает!)

Все ключи у конечных устройств одинаковые в плане конфигураций.

Подумал, что устройства Apple как-то передают мое местоположение, и поэтому OpenAI блочит соединение. Поставил регион США - все так же проблема.

Если есть догадки, ответы или хотя бы совет куда копать, прошу помочь.

Comment: Wireguard не надежен и банится по всей стране. Используйте другие системы. Например Xray proxy, Shadowsocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenAI обновили алгоритмы определения региона, и сейчас ChatGPT недоступен при развертывании личной сети на облачном сервере, даже если сервер размещен за пределами РФ.
Источник - https://timeweb.cloud/docs/timeweb-private-vpn/private-vpn-faq

У меня аналогичная проблема на всех ОС, даже если через CURl отправлять запрос напрямую с VPS

PS:
Я вот тут - https://app.bitlaunch.io развернул сервер и настроил wireguard и проблема исчезла.